Diophantine equation: finding when a degree $2$ expression in $x$ and $y$ is a perfect square.
For what values of $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ the expression $(2x-y)² + 4x + 1 - 6y$ is square of an integer?
I figured out that the expression equals $1$ for $$(x,y) = (n(n+3)/2 , n(n+1)) \quad \text{and}  \quad  (x,y) = (n(n+3)/2 , (n+2)(n+3)),$$
I figured out that the expression equals $4$ for $$(x,y) = (2n^2+2n-1 , 4n^2-1) \quad \text{and}  \quad  (x,y) = (2n^2+2n-1 , 4n^2+8n+3),$$
But how do I find out in general a paramterization of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $n$ for a given $k^2?$
For another approach,  I substituted $x=X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$ in $(2x-y)² + 4x + 1 - 6y = k^2$ to get the Quadratic form $4X^2+Y^2-4XY+4XZ-6YZ+(1-k^2)Z^2.$ I want to convert it in a diagonal quadratic form and apply the Legendre's criteria but I am stuck.
Please help me with this. Thank you :)

You can solve it by using Alpertron calculator, link: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Note that your two expressions for $k^2=1$ and the two expressions for $k^2=4$ are not really different parameterizations. In case of $k^2=1,$ you get the one from the other by substituting $n$ with $-n-3$. In case of $k^2=4,$ you get the one from the other by substituting $n$ with $-n-1$.

@ReinhardMeier Okay, but why does this happen?

If you set $2x-y-1=u$ and $y-x=v$, you get a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$, which means that each integer solution for $(x,y)$ is also an integer solution for $(u,v)$ and the other way round.
We have $x=u+v+1$ and $y=u+2v+1$. Therefore
$$
k^2 \\
= (2x-y)^2+4x+1-6y \\
= (u+1)^2+4(u+v+1)+1-6(u+2v+1) \\
= u^2+2u+1+4u+4v+4+1-6u-12v-6 \\
= u^2 -8v
$$
This in turn means that we have $8v=u^2-k^2$. It is easy to check that the difference of two squares is a multiple of $8$ in the following three cases
\begin{eqnarray}
(u,k) &=& (2m-1, 2n-1) \\
\text{or}\;\;(u,k) &=& (4m-2, 4n-2) \\
\text{or}\;\;(u,k) &=& (4m, 4n) 
\end{eqnarray}
with $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.
For even $k$ and even $u$, we can use the fact that the difference between $k$ and $u$ must be a multiple of $4$. We can use a different parameterization and reduce the number of cases to two:
\begin{eqnarray}
(u,k) &=& (2m-1, \;2n-1) \\
\text{or}\;\;(u,k) &=& (2n+4m, \;2n) 
\end{eqnarray}
with $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.
First case: $(u,k)=(2m-1, 2n-1)$. We get
$$
v=\frac{u^2-k^2}{8}=\frac{(2m-1)^2-(2n-1)^2}{8}\\
=\frac{4m^2-4m-4n^2+4n}{8}=\frac{m^2-m}{2}-\frac{n^2-n}{2} \\
=\binom{m}{2}-\binom{n}{2}
$$
This gives us the first possible parameterization
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& u+v+1 = 2m + \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2} \\
y &=& u+2v+1 = 2m + 2\binom{m}{2} - 2\binom{n}{2} \\
k &=& 2n-1
\end{eqnarray}
Second case: $(u,k)=(2n+4m, 2n)$. We get
$$
v=\frac{u^2-k^2}{8}=\frac{4n^2+16nm+16m^2-4n^2}{8}\\
=2m^2+2mn
$$
This gives us the second possible parameterization
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& u+v+1 = 2n+4m + 2m^2 + 2mn +1 \\
y &=& u+2v+1 = 2n+4m + 4m^2 + 4mn +1 \\
k &=& 2n
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks a lot for the detailed work. I have a small question: For $k=1$ or any odd number, your parametrization gives just one value of $y$ while as mentioned in the question, two values of $y$ satisfy the equation. Could you please explain that as well?

As mentioned earlier, those "two values" are not really different solutions. You get the same pair $(x,y)$ for a different value of $n$ (in your question) or $m$ (in my answer). You step through the different values of $n$ in a different order, but the set of pairs $(x,y)$ generated by those numbers stays the same, because each pair occurs twice.

$$k^2=4x^2-4x(y-1)+y^2-6y+1\iff4x^2-4x(y-1)+y^2-6y+1-k^2=0$$
$$\implies x=\cdots=\dfrac{y-1\pm\sqrt{k^2+4y}}2$$
Now, as $x$ is an integer,  $\sqrt{d^2+4y}$ must be an integer $=+e$(say)
$\implies y=\dfrac{e^2-k^2}4$
As $y$ is an integer, $e,k$ must have the same parity, WLOG $e=k+2f\implies y=?$
Consequently, $x=\cdots=\dfrac{(e\pm2)^2-k^2}8-1=\cdots=\dfrac{(f-1)(f+1)}2-1$
So, $f$ must be odd

Thank you for your answer but I still have some questions:
How do you get an expression for $x$ in terms of $f$ only? How does it completely characterize $x,y$ when $k$ is some fixed integer.?
